# Не открывает активити после авторизации

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь подключить авторизацию с помощью google но после того как я нажимаю на выбор эмейла, окно выбора просто сворачивается и всё, а следующее акивити не открывается!

Мой MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 101;
    private Button googlesignin, fblogin, loginemail, loginphone;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        googlesignin = findViewById(R.id.googlesignin);
        fblogin = findViewById(R.id.fblogin);
        loginemail = findViewById(R.id.loginemail);
        loginphone = findViewById(R.id.loginphone);


        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


        //Обработка нажатия кнопки авторизации google
        googlesignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });


    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, user.getEmail()+user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Лог ошибок

```
GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (CHANGE-ME)} android
```

Comment: у вас ошибка 404 в логе вроде все видно, проверьте данные которые используете для входа и точку входа

Comment: Данные верны это 100%, а вот про точку входа не совсем понял, точнее вообще ничего.

Comment: суть в том что у гугла может не быть того места в которое вы стучитесь для получения искомого ответа

Comment: Firebase проект создал, подключился к нему, указал hash, указал почту, json загрузил в проекте студии

Comment: а у вас сообщение всплывает про неудачную авторизацию?

Comment: Что-то я не нашёл, где вы получаете тексты из полей логина, мейла, телефона. И куда их передаёте.

Comment: Сообщение получаю gms.common.api.apiexception 10

Comment: У меня авторизация не с помощью логина и пароля, а с помощью google auth

Answer (score 0):

404 то есть страница не найдена. Перепроверь токен и попробуй пересоздать